# How to pass vertex color information into GLSL shaders program Unity

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, glsl, shader

my question is how to pass per vertex color data into shader program in unity.
Unlike in OpenGL c++ code, we define attributes and link it with shader program.

Example:

```
float vertices []
{
     //vertex pos                   //vertex color
    .0.0, 1.0, 0.0,                   1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     1.0, 2.0, 1.0                    0.0, 1.0, 0.0
}
```

and then we pass the data by parsing it based on size and offset size into vertex buffer.
In unity "gl_vertex" take all vertex position data, but i want to pass color data too so that fragment shader can use it.

i want something like this,

```
 //vertex shader
in vec4 color
out vec4 Color
void main()
{
gl_Position = gl_vertex //working fine
Color = color //expecting
}

//fragment shader
out vec4 fragcolor
in vec4 Color
void main()
{
outColor = Color
}
```

Comment: You mean vertex color from a 3d model to shader?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the unity manual. OpenGL shouldn't be tagged here as GL shaders are completely different from what unity uses in a .shader file. See  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Reference.html for the latest Unity Shader Reference.

Comment: You _are_ trying to [use GLSL](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-GLSLShaderPrograms.html), correct? It's not entirely clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Vertex colors can be set for a `Mesh` like described in [1].

And to use them in a shader, add a member to the vertex shader input struct and adorn it with `: COLOR` like described in [2].

[1] Unity Scripting API; Mesh.colors; https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-colors.html

[2] Unity Manual; Providing vertex data to vertex programs; https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/SL-VertexProgramInputs.html